# Regular expressions and lists

Tags: regex, list

I have lists with " · " (dot) in the html and output. I need to replace that with an actual `<ul><li>...</li></ul>`

This sounds tough but does anyone have any ideas?

The html is:

· List item 1
 · List item 2

(wrapped in paragraph tags)

And I need it to be

```
<ul>
<li>List Item 1</li>
<li>List Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Do you want to do it client side or server side?  If server side, what language are you working in?

Comment: Can you post the html output you have with the dots, so we can look how the regex should look like.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the dot from the html and give the list a css of `ul { list-style-type: circle; }`

For more values for the css attribute, check http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/list-style-type

Comment: There actually is no <ul> or <li> tags. The html is rendered as " · "

Comment: Are you asking how to use the `ul` and `li` tags? (please include what code you have, your question is really hard to understand)